# How to handle newline character in HIVE on HBase?

Tags: java, hbase, apache-hive

I am inserting data into `hbase` from my java program.  As we need to convert everything into byte arrays to insert into hbase I am doing so.  But when there is any newline character in my input string, it is storing hexadecimal values in hbase (Eg: I tried to insert the string `"prasad\r\nchowdary"` but in `hbase` it is like `prasad\x0D\x0Achowdary`).

My problem is when the data is like this in hbase, when I try to query this table from hive, my jdbc resultset is been repeating two time for single row.

So how to avoid it converting `\r\n` to hexadecimal when inserting into hbase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put new line or any other set of characters in your string the modify them such that java treats them as a string.

Convert "prasad\r\nchowdary" to "prasad\r\nchowdary"

That is just use escape character "\" before new line then convert it to Bytes. It should look something like.

```
String name = "prasad\\r\\nchowdary";
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("family"),Bytes.toBytes("qualifier"),Bytes.toBytes("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "prasad\r\nchowdary";

str = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str);

Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(str));

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(p.toJSON());

System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(json.getString("row")));
```